# What design patterns are used in Spring framework?

Tags: design-patterns, spring

What design patterns are used in Spring framework?

Comment: It includes more than 10 patterns including ..MVC, Front controller, 
View Helper, Singleton, Prototype, Factory etc .

http://www.javabench.in/2012/02/design-patterns-being-used-in-spring.html

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There are loads of different design patterns used, but there are a few obvious ones:

- Proxy - used heavily in [AOP](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies), and [remoting](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/remoting.html).
- Singleton - beans defined in spring config files are singletons by default.
- Template method - used extensively to deal with boilerplate repeated code (such as closing connections cleanly, etc..). For example [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate), [JmsTemplate](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jms.html#jms-jmstemplate), [JpaTemplate](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa-template).

---

Update following comments: For MVC, you might want to read the [MVC Reference](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html)

Some obvious patterns in use in MVC:

- [Model View Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) :-)   . The advantage with Spring MVC is that your controllers are POJOs as opposed to being servlets. This makes for easier testing of controllers. One thing to note is that the controller is only required to return a logical view name, and the view selection is left to a separate [ViewResolver](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver). This makes it easier to reuse controllers for different view technologies.
- [Front Controller](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/frontcontroller-135648.html). Spring provides [DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) to ensure an incoming request gets dispatched to your controllers.
- [View Helper](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/viewhelper-139885.html) - Spring has a number of custom JSP tags, and velocity macros, to assist in separating code from presentation in views.

Comment: Thanks,
What are the design patterns used in Spring MVC module?

Comment: I don't think Spring implements singleton for the beans. Note that a singleton scoped bean will have a single instance **per application context**. So, if your application has two Spring contexts, they load a same singleton bean `Foo` and you retrieve the instance of `Foo` per context, you will get two different object references. Instead, the design pattern applied here is [flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza  you mean that spring does not have singleton objects? please explain me with some clarification.

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal there's a significal difference between Singleton pattern and singleton instance (note the upper/lowercase S). Singleton pattern is about maintaining a single instance of the object through the whole application. What Spring does when detecting a singleton bean is to create a single instance **per application context**. The application context is the core component of Spring, and serves to delegate creation and retrieval of objects. The singleton bean is created only once per application context.

Comment: Links for model view controller,front controller and view helped takes to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html. Could you please update the answer with a working link?

Comment: Bringing up `JdbcTemplate` and its friends as an example of template method is very common, but I think they have little to do with that pattern (apart from the name). Or else we can call pretty much all cases where you extend a class to override some protected methods an example of the template method pattern.

Comment: @toolkit I come across "The Spring Framework codifies formalized design patterns as first-class objects that you can integrate into your own application"  this statement while reading spring from docs what does this mean.

Answer (score 12):

And of course dependency injection, or IoC (inversion of control), which is central to the whole BeanFactory/ApplicationContext stuff.

Answer (score 10):

The DI thing actually is some kind of strategy pattern. Whenever you want to be some logic/implementation exchangeable you typically find an interface and an appropriate setter method on the host class to wire your custom implementation of that interface.

Comment: Answer from the Master itself. @Oliver could you state more patterns here?

Answer (score 8):

Spring is a collection of best-practise API patterns, you can write up a shopping list of them as long as your arm. The way that the API is designed encourages you (but doesn't force you) to follow these patterns, and half the time you follow them without knowing you are doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Service Locator Pattern - ServiceLocatorFactoryBean keeps information of all the beans in the context. When client code asks for a service (bean) using name, it simply locates that bean in the context and returns it. Client code does not need to write spring related code to locate a bean.

Answer (score 2):

Observer-Observable: it is used in ApplicationContext's event mechanism

Answer (score 1):

Factory pattern is also used for loading beans through BeanFactory and Application context.

Answer (score 1):

Factory Method patter: BeanFactory for creating instance of an object
Singleton : instance type can be singleton for a context
Prototype : instance type can be prototype.
Builder pattern: you can also define a method in a class who will be responsible for creating complex instance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring container generates bean objects depending on the bean scope (singleton, prototype etc..). So this looks like implementing [Abstract Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). In the Spring's internal implementation, I am sure each scope should be tied to specific factory kind class.